# Return the extract index of a number in the other array

Tags: python

thanks for take sometime to read this.Here is my idea but i don't know how to make it work:
Input: i have created a array by using this filter

```
z = ([x for x in frq[indexes] if 100 <= x <= 200])
```

then its will create a `array(z)` that have the number get through the filter.

Output: it will take the number in the new array to find their location(index) in side the `frq`[indexes]

Thanks for reading this

p/s: sorry for my bad english :(((

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output to clarify what exactly you are looking for ?

Comment: Input: a array frq[indexes] go through the filter(z = ([x for x in frq[indexes] if 100 <= x <= 200])) to create a new array got the numbers that go through the filter then take that numbers to find their location in frq[indexes]

Comment: Output: their location in the frq[indexes]

Comment: Can there be duplicates in `indexes`? Can you just change `z` to capture the indexes too?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

```
z=[x for x in range(len(frq)) if 100 <= frq[x] <= 200]
```

now `z` will contain the indexes of elements from **`frq`** array

for example

```
frq=[10,101,202,150]
z=[x for x in range(len(frq)) if 100 <= frq[x] <= 200]
```

output:

```
z= [1, 3]  # that is 101 and 150
```

If this is not what you are expecting you are requested to please ask question properly specifying things clearly

Answer (score 0):

```
frq[indexes] = ....
z = ([x for x in frq[indexes] if 100 <= x <= 200])

locations = []
for el in z: # this will get the locations inside frq into a list
  locations.append(frq[indexes].index(el))

print(locations)
```